# Pushing server IPs into array

Tags: perl, loops

Here is code which works... Problem is when from some site can't be taken IP, scrip stop. Is there some way to make script work even IP form some site can't be taken? I need somting like in VB On Error Resume Next...

```
our $file = abs_path("site.txt");

open (FH, "< $file") or die "Can't open $file for read: $!";
our @lines;
while (<FH>) {
    chomp($hostname="$_"); #change this to your hostname
our($addr)=inet_ntoa((gethostbyname($hostname))[4]);
our @newarr;
push(@newarr,$addr); }
```

Comment: Never use `our` unless forced to. Use `my`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl's exception handling mechanism is [eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html).

I would re-write your code (untested) as follows:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Socket;

my $file = 'test.txt';

open my $fh, '<', $file
    or die "Can't open $file for read: $!";

my @addr;

while (my $hostname = <$fh>) {
    last unless $hostname =~ /\S/;
    $hostname =~ s/\s+\z//;

    my $ip = gethostbyname $hostname;
    $ip = defined($ip) ? inet_ntoa $ip : '';

    push @addr, [$hostname, $ip];
}

close $fh
    or die "Cannot close '$file': $!";

use YAML;
print Dump \@addr;
```

Note the following:

- Bareword file handles are package global
- `our` variables have package scope
- If you are going to assign the return value of `<$fh>` to a variable, do so in the `while` condition, without messing with `$_`

When posting code, please post code that at least has a reasonable chance of compiling.